# Running .jspx on apache tomcat

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, weblogic, jspx

We run an application written with "jspx" (Java Server Page with XML I guess), it runs on web-logic but the web-logic is down currently.
I wish to know if I could copy the files and put it under Apache tomcat.
I have actually tried that but I got some errors which makes me feel Apache tomcat is strictly for "jsp" and not "jspx".

If my assuption is right then what else can I use to compile a ".jspx" program aside from weblogic?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `jspx` are simply `jsp` files with *well-formed XML* instead of "just any html".

Try editing your `tomcat/conf/web.xml` and add another mapping for the jsp-servlet:

```
<!-- Existing mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- New mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But... for [Tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) this is already in place. Can you share the error messages you got?